# SSMS new data is not showing

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms-2012

I am using `SSMS 2012 express`  and I have got into some case, maybe you can help me.

I am running a simple script like:

```
select * from table.
```

The table gets new data every day by some service. But I can see the new data only if I would `reconnect` to the database or `refresh` the `tables`.

Otherwise I don't see the new data.

What could be the issue

Comment: What does `refresh the tables` mean?

Comment: When you right click on the tables folder and click refresh, or just select tables folder and press F5 or click the dedicated refresh button on one of the bars, not sure what that bar is called.